# the project file has been renamed or is no longer in the solution

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I am trying to fix this error:

```
the project file '' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution
```

and I have tried all the other posts' solutions, and nothing is working, I tried adding the preferences for the project but it also won't let me. When I click to Add New Reference, and choose the references and click Ok it gives me the same error.

I have many projects that I want to build in the solution but it's not working.

(Also it's upgraded from an old version of VS to VS2012)

Any help is highly appreciated because I'm literally out of ideas here (and read all threads)
Thank you

Comment: No solution but my advice would be to recreate the projects from scratch in your current version of VS. In my experience project upgrades often do not go well in VS. It's a bit of effort but you end up in a better place than if you patch whatever the issue is.

Comment: My guess for a quick fix: rename the faulty file to any random name (ex: 'myfile_faulty.c') and create a new file with the true name. Copy the code from 'myfile_faulty.' in this new file and check if this compiles